# Absolute positioning breaks page layout under 1024px container width

Tags: html, css, absolute

Building this site and noticed that under 1100px it breaks (footer and header). I know its because of the absolutely positioned elements that hang on the side of the pages but can't figure out how to make sure the header/footer are 100% of the browser width.

Since its a parallax site I will spare the nonsense of pasting all the extra markup in here and send you to the [direct link](http://pbj.me/IBM2/)

Any thoughts or ideas would be fantastic.

Comment: Try and give the relevant code in your question please (or link to a fiddle).

Comment: What do you want to happen under 1100px? You'll probably need to set a width/min-width for a wrapper that contains both header and content (so they are both the same width). You also currently get a horizontal scroll bar around 1285px, so some of your containing divs could use `overflow: hidden`.

Comment: @cjspurg Yea I had to solve for the horizontal scroll. At this point anything under 1100px breaks completely. iPhone basically shows 25% of the layout and just cuts off the rest. I've realized its because of the 1024px wrapper but not sure how to solve for that otherwise. At the least I just want a scaled back version of the site.